# trying to figure out why my form's datagrid only saves the first 35 rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, save, windows-forms-designer

My windows form loads a csv file and displays the data in the data grid. but when i click the save button it only saves the first 35 rows in the grid and cuts the rest off. it is always the same spot where it cuts off no matter how much i add to the data

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication19
{
    public partial class WoodStock : Form
    {
        public WoodStock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Opens csv file and splits the data seperated by a ',' into cells
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\StockFile\Stocklist.csv");
            string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (string c in columnnames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c);

            }

            string newline;
            while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                string[] values = newline.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = values[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            file.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            
        }

        

        private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved.");
            System.IO.StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\StockFile\stocklist.csv");
            
            string columnHeaderText = "";

            //Collecting DataGridView Column Header Text
            int countColumn = dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1;

            if (countColumn >= 0)
            {
                columnHeaderText = dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
            {
                columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ',' + dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            }

            //Writing Column Header Text in File
            fileWriter.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);

            //Collecting Data Rows
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRowObject in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                //Checking for New Row in DataGridView 
                if (!dataRowObject.IsNewRow)
                {
                    string dataFromGrid = "";

                    dataFromGrid = dataRowObject.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                    {
                        dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                    }

                    //Writing Data Rows in File         
                    fileWriter.WriteLine(dataFromGrid);
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many rows are in the original document?

Comment: Maybe you only have 35 rows that are not new?

Comment: there are 40+ rows in the csv file not including the headers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't close the `StreamWriter`, so *not only* does it hold the file-lock open, it also doesn't flush the buffer into the file properly. Because it's `IDisposable`, there's a **far** better way to write this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Opens csv file and splits the data seperated by a ',' into cells
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"..."))
    {
        string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string c in columnnames)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(c);

        }

        string newline;
        while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = newline.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = values[i];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}

private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved.");

    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"..."))
    {
        string columnHeaderText = "";

        //Collecting DataGridView Column Header Text
        int countColumn = dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1;

        if (countColumn >= 0)
        {
            columnHeaderText = dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
        {
            columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ',' + dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }

        //Writing Column Header Text in File
        fileWriter.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);

        //Collecting Data Rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRowObject in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //Checking for New Row in DataGridView 
            if (!dataRowObject.IsNewRow)
            {
                string dataFromGrid = "";

                dataFromGrid = dataRowObject.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                {
                    dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                }

                //Writing Data Rows in File         
                fileWriter.WriteLine(dataFromGrid);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to put the *actual* file names back in, I was using `stocklist.csv` and `stocklist2.csv` for them to see what happened.

Now you don't manually need to call `file.Close();` either time, it's automatic at the end of the `using` block.